# Unable to tap button by coordinates in Appium by using w3c_actions

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-ios

I am unable to tap the button by coordinates in Appium on an iOS simulator device.
I am using w3c.actions as actionButtons are deprecated.

```
action = ActionChains(context.driver)
action.w3c_actions = ActionBuilder(context.driver, mouse=PointerInput(interaction.POINTER_TOUCH, 'tap'))
action.w3c_actions.pointer_action.move_to_location(260, 160)
action.w3c_actions.pointer_action.click()
action.w3c_actions.perform()
```

I've found this code via stack overflow and I was using Appium Inspector to specifically tap the button at coordinates x = 260 and y = 160.

There is no error message, it just goes to the next step, I don't know if the tap happened at all.

The reason why I am using coordinates is that the element is not visible when looking at the source.

The app is a Wikipedia app on ios devices.

In order to reproduce my issue:

Skip onboarding -> Settings -> Log in -> Join Wikipedia(not able to tap it)